# Why I get a black model when I load a GLTF model which have materials?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, gltf

I m trying to load my 3d model which have glb format.
Here's the code:

What I exept:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4IB0.png) 
What I have: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2905D.png)

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(1000, 1000);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1000 / 1000, 0.1, 1000)
camera.position.z = 0.5;

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');

const gltfLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  const url = 'hub.glb';
  gltfLoader.load(url, (gltf) => {
    const root = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(root);

  });

var render = () => {   
    requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
  
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

When I check the variables, the color material is set and correct. 
Here's the variable explorer: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf9ri.png)

Thank you !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding some lights to your scene:

```js
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.4 );
scene.add( ambientLight );

const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xefefff, 1.5 );
dirLight.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );
scene.add( dirLight );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It's working now after 4 hours !!

Answer (score 0):

For some projects is better to use environment texture (hdr). You can get some texture on - https://polyhaven.com/hdris.

To add texture to project you must load it. Use RGBELoader

```
import {RGBELoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js";
async loadRGBE(url: string): Promise<Texture> {
const RGBELoader = new RGBELoader();
return new Promise<Texture>((resolve, reject) => {
  RGBELoader.load(
    url,
    (texture) => {
      texture.mapping = EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
      resolve(texture);
    },
    undefined,
    (error) => {
      reject(error);
    }
  );
});
}
   ... some code...
const texture = await loadRGBE("Link_to_hdr");
this.scene.environment = texture;
```

for set how much will object react to environment light you can traverse whole object and set envMapIntensity. Like this

```
model?.traverse((child: Object3D) => {
  if (child instanceof Mesh) {
    if (child.material instanceof MeshStandardMaterial) {
      child.material.envMapIntensity = 0.5;

    };
 };
});
```